# Where to search for free C/C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, c

Where to search for free C/C++ libraries?

Comment: Do you have specific functionality in mind? You'll get better, more targeted recommendations if you can mention what it is you need from a library.

Comment: The Internet is a good place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)

avoid [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html), as they aren't really free and are spreading like a virus through the rest of your project

use [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html)

Comment: GPL only spreads to the rest of your project if you distribute binaries, though. Even then, you can always distribute the binaries under the terms allowed by the GPL, and *also* distribute your source with whatever more permissive license you prefer.

Comment: GPL spreads like a virus? I'd say Apple spreads like a virus and GPL spreads like a vineyard.

Answer (score 2):

I usualy use google.com )
codeproject.com
codeguru.com

Answer (score 1):

[GNU](http://www.gnu.org/) has a [large number](http://www.gnu.org/software/software.html) of them.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the links are already mentioned by others.

If you have a particular functionality in mind, you can search for the same in Wikipedia also. Along with giving info about the functionality, it would have mostly listed the softwares (Libraries included) available also.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggests three solutions:

- [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).
- [conan](https://github.com/conan-io/conan).
- Your Linux package manager (`apt-get`, `pacman`, etc).

Although they aren't centralizes as PyPI is for Python or RubyGems is for Ruby, vcpkg and conan are good websites for discovering and installing new C/C++ libraries.

Your Linux package manager can be useful for installing them if it has a comprehensive package database.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fffaraz/awesome-cpp maintains a currated list of libs, most of them are open source.  there are a number of lists like this, just google 'awesome C++ list', but i find this one the most complete.